# Score not being calculated correctly

Tags: vb.net

Hi I'm created a program for a project and I've now started running some tests and the score for the user isn't being calculated correctly and I believe that it can't compare the answer given to the correct answer. I'm very confused and need any help that can be given. My code looks like this, any confusing parts and I'll try and explain.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class QuestionScreen

Dim score As Integer = 0
Dim count As Integer
Dim Difficulty_ext As String
Dim questions, answers As New List(Of String)()
Private i As Integer

Sub ReadFile()

    If Main.Diff_DDown.Text = "Easy" Then
        Difficulty_ext = "questions - Easy"
    ElseIf Main.Diff_DDown.Text = "Medium" Then
        Difficulty_ext = "questions - Medium"
    Else
        Difficulty_ext = "questions - Difficult"
    End If

    Randomize()
    Dim countline = File.ReadAllLines("c:\Users\Alice\Desktop\programme files\" & Difficulty_ext & ".txt").Length
    Dim numline As Integer
    Dim values() As String

    Using sr As New StreamReader("c:\Users\Alice\Desktop\programme files\" & Difficulty_ext & ".txt")
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
            values = sr.ReadLine().Split(","c)
            questions.Add(values(0))
            answers.Add(values(1))
        End While
    End Using

    numline = Int(Rnd() * countline)
    For i As Integer = 0 To numline
        Question.Text = questions(i)
        Act_ANS.Text = answers(i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Pass_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pass_Btn.Click
    If count < 10 Then
        Call ReadFile()
        count = count + 1
        Ans_TxtBx.Text = ""
        Hid_Score.Text = score
    Else
        ResultsScreen.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Submit_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Submit_Btn.Click
    If count < 10 Then
        Call ReadFile()
        count = count + 1
        If Ans_TxtBx.Text = answers(i) Then

            score = score + 1
        End If
        Hid_Score.Text = score
    Else
        ResultsScreen.Show()
        Me.Hide()
        count = 0
    End If
    Ans_TxtBx.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub QuestionScreen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call ReadFile()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There are lots of errors in your code, but I think the main one is that the "Private i as Integer" is never initialized. You read it to compare your answers but you never set it anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

OK..... Try this, I have debugged your code trying to leave it pretty much as you had it,  there were a number of problems, nothing major just a few lines of code in the wrong place....

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Dim score As Integer = 0
Dim count As Integer
Dim Difficulty_ext As String
Dim questions, answers As New List(Of String)()
Private i As Integer

Sub ReadFile()

    If Diff_DDown.Text = "Easy" Then
        Difficulty_ext = "questions - Easy"
    ElseIf Diff_DDown.Text = "Medium" Then
        Difficulty_ext = "questions - Medium"
    Else
        Difficulty_ext = "questions - Difficult"
    End If

    Randomize()
    Try

        Dim countline = File.ReadAllLines("c:\Users\Alice\Desktop\programme files\" & Difficulty_ext & ".txt").Length
        Dim numline As Integer
        Dim values() As String

        ' clear the list of questions and answers
        answers.Clear()
        questions.Clear()
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Using sr As New StreamReader("c:\Users\Alice\Desktop\programme files\" & Difficulty_ext & ".txt")
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                values = sr.ReadLine().Split(","c)
                questions.Add(values(0))
                answers.Add(values(1))
            End While
        End Using

        numline = Int(Rnd() * countline)
        For i = 0 To numline
            Question.Text = questions(i)
            Act_ANS.Text = answers(i)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Pass_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pass_Btn.Click
    If count < 10 Then
        count = count + 1
        Ans_TxtBx.Text = ""
        Hid_Score.Text = score
    Else
        ResultsScreen.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
    Call ReadFile() '  move this to the bottom
End Sub

Public Sub Submit_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Submit_Btn.Click
    If count < 10 Then
        count = count + 1
        If Ans_TxtBx.Text = answers(i - 1) Then ' need to subtract 1 here

            score = score + 1
        End If
        Hid_Score.Text = score
    Else
        ResultsScreen.Show()
        Me.Hide()
        count = 0
    End If
    Ans_TxtBx.Text = ""
    Call ReadFile() '  move this to the bottom
End Sub

Private Sub QuestionScreen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call ReadFile()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hi can I ask why is it necessary to subtract 1? It would be great if you could explain thanks

Comment: @Alice Hartley Yeah I see that was your original problem now, I didn't want to alter your code too much and I was in a rush too, The For-Next loop in the ReadFile sub is incrementing 'i' by 1 more than numline... eg. If numline = 4 then 'i' will loop round to = 5 before the for\next loop exit's, this then won't match up with the correct answer in Submit_Btn_Click event where you check using the value of 'i' ...

Comment: yeah that now comes up with an error where the code is highlighted yellow, it's saying this: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." but as the file doesn't have 0 values in so I'm slightly confused on why it's throwing this error

Comment: Ummm... 'code is highlighted yellow' I can't see yellow highlight... Make sure that you have at least one question and answer in each of the Difficulty_ext files.... like so.... <Question>, <Answer> Also check that you have a comma separating all the questions from answers... I loaded the code above straight from here into Visual Studio and it worked with my Q,A files

Comment: Don't worry I worked out the problem, it was the fact that i was being changed so all I did is set it a hidden label and then used that. I know I think that's what you were trying to get at but for some reason that code didn't work but thank you so much for your help

Comment: Well done. Glad you figured it out, is always best if you can fix your own code rather than copy someone eases, you learn a lot more that way.....